# ExtJS 7.7 grid with plugin.cellediting seems to not open combo when click on combo trigger [EXTJS-29966]

Tags: javascript, extjs, combobox, grid, tagfield

When using a Ext.grid.Panel with 'cellediting' plugin, click on on row with tagfields/combos to start editing the field then click on combo/tagfield trigger (right triangle), seems to not open drop down values.
Works only if you press down arrow from keyboard.

Sencha Fiddle live preview: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3ll2
(there are some commbined bugs for grids in this preview)

Answer (score 0):

My Current fix:

```
Ext.define("Ext.fix.view.Table", {
    override: "Ext.view.Table",
    /**
     * @fix for EXTJS-29966 "combo trigger not working in cell editor".
     */
    focusPosition: function () {
        if (Ext.getVersion().equals("7.7.0.31")) {
            return Ext.emptyFn();
        }
        return this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that fixes the issue. Here is short override and yours is good. Anyone can use that. This issue is seen only on 7.7 version.

```
Ext.define('null', {
    override: "Ext.view.Table",
    focusPosition: function () {
        Ext.emptyFn();
    },
});
```

Comment: yes, I'm using the Ext.getVersion().equals("7.7.0.31") just to make sure my custom package works in more apps with different versions. I have a common package that I share with multiple apps and some of them have different version of extjs.